# Kubernetes scale down specific pods

Tags: replication, kubernetes

I have a set of Pods running commands that can take up to a couple seconds.  There is a process that keeps track of open request & which Pod the request is running on.  I'd like the use that information when scaling down pods - either by specifying which pods to try to leave up, or specifying which pods to shut down.  Is it possible to specify this type of information when changing the # of replicas, e.g. I want X replicas, try not to kill my long running tasks on pods A, B, C?

Comment: Not yet from what I know. I remember reading about an open  issue where they are trying to implement some kind of check to see if the pod can be closed or not.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63203913/2147383) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've been looking for a solution to this myself, and i also can't find one out of the box.
however, there might be a workaround (would love it if you could test and confirm)

steps:
 1. delete replication controller
 2. delete X desired pods
 3. recreate replication controller of size X

Comment: also it looks like you can stop and start the replication controller, so maybe it's better to stop it, delete the pod, change the replicas with the scale command and start it again.

Answer (score 6):

You can annotation  specific pod with `controller.kubernetes.io/pod-deletion-cost: -999` and enable `PodDeletionCost` featuregate. This feature is implement alpha in 1.21 and beta in 1.22.

> `controller.kubernetes.io/pod-deletion-cost` annotation can be set to offer a hint on the cost of deleting a pod compared to other pods belonging to the same ReplicaSet. Pods with lower deletion cost are deleted first.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/99163
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/101080

Comment: This is true but sometimes it doesn't get honoured.

Comment: @skygeek is that documented, that it does not get honoured?  Or something you've seen only in your own experience?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't currently possible. When you scale down the number of replicas, the system will choose one to remove; there isn't a way to "hint" at which one you'd like it to remove.

One thing you can do is you can change the labels on running pods which can affect their membership in the replication controller. This can be used to quarantine pods that you want to debug (so that they won't be part of a service or removed by a scaling event) but might also be possible to use for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl scale deployment --replicas=5 my-app`

Answer (score -1):

As mention above, the workaround for this action should be something like this:

> alias k=kubectl

> k delete pod <pods_name> && k scale --replicas=<current_replicas - 1> deploy/<name_of_deployment>

Make sure you don't have an active hpa resource that is related to the deployment.

Comment: After deletion the pod will be immediately recreated, and after scale down kube will still select any pod